# Hugo and js. Add Title to header on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, hugo

On my static Hugo website I need the word "Critique" in the bottom of my sticky header on List.html page of the critique section and on the single.html of the section before scrolling. But on scrolling I would like to add the article title only on the single.html page but not on the list.html page. This is the logic I need somewhere in my partials/page-title.html

```
    {{ $page-scroll := "no-scroll" }}
    <script>
        $(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            ${page-scroll} = "scroll";
        }}
    </script>
    
    <section class="page-title">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-10">
          {{ if eq .Section "critique" }} <h3>Critique {{ if eq $page-scroll "scroll" }} / {{ .Title}} {{end}}</h3> {{ end }}
         </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Unfortunately the script doesn't change $page-scroll variable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hugo variables are referenced like this:

```
{{ $page-scroll }}
```

However, you are looking for something like this:

```
<script>
    $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = 'inline';
    }}
</script>

{{ if eq .Section "critique" }} 
  <h3>Critique<span id="showme" style="display: none;"> / {{ .Title}}</span></h3>
{{ end }}
```